# DirectoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password }); is giving access denied error in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, directoryservices

```
DirectoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });
```

is giving error in ASP.NET application, while it is working perfectly in a Console Application.

This is the error I'm getting:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

The Internal Error is `Access Denied`.

Comment: {"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."} This is the error i am getting. Internal Error is Access Denied.

Answer (score 2):

The security context ASP.NET runs under is different than when you run something from the command line. Check what your Application Pool is running as. It usually runs as a low privileged user.

Comment: I give permission to app pool account in AD as admin. Still getting the same.

Answer (score -1):

The above questions is solve

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DomainName", null, "UserName", "Password"))
{
    using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "username"))
    {
            user.SetPassword("Password");
    }
}
```